# Missing vertical stripes table

Tags: tables, multicolumn, vertical

Hi I made a big table using tabularX but I am missing some vertical stripes on the top.

I've been playing around with the code but can't seem to fix it.
[image]

My code looks like this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X | X | X | X | X |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Applicatie}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Techniek}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Hardware en platform}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Voordelen}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Nadelen}} 
\endhead
\tabularnewline \hline
ODVIC (On-Demand Virtual Counselor) & Avatar via BMI \footnote{Brief Motivational Intervention} om alcoholgebruik te verminderen & Computer & Beter dan tekst-based aanpak & Portability, invoer via dialoog (tijdrovender), kwalitatieve data (minder accuraat)
\tabularnewline \hline
  Soberdiary & Alcohol test & Breathalyzer en mobiele applicatie & portability, accuraat, geautomatiseerd & Duurder, complexer in gebruik
  \tabularnewline \hline
  It's time to eat & Avatar die gezond ontbijt stimuleert voor kinderen \& foto's van maaltijden & Mobiele applicatie & Dierlijke avatar motiveert kinderen, customization, snel, eenvoudig & Accuraatheid (foto's) 
  \tabularnewline \hline
  Menu-Match & Foto's en GPS signaal (vergelijkt met db foto's) & GSM-applicatie & Restaurant ondersteuning, snel, accuraat & Maaltijd moet exact hetzelfde zijn, moeilijk bruikbaar voor thuis
  \tabularnewline \hline
  Platemate & Foto's en mechanical turks & GSM camera en mobiele applicatie & Heel accuraat, snel, eenvoudig & Omslachtig, langzaam (niet real-time), duurder
  \tabularnewline \hline
  Jog Falls & Foto's en database entry & GSM-applicatie en pc applicatie & Eenvoudig, snel & Accuraatheid, culturele verschillen \footnote{Applicatie werd gebruikt in India en doordat er daar met de handen gegeten wordt, is het raar om een foto van je maaltijd te maken.}
  \tabularnewline \hline
  FoodLog & Foto's uploaden of flickr & GSM-Applicatie & Snel, eenvoudig & Accuraatheid
  \tabularnewline \hline
  Life-Mash & Passive notifications, hoeveelheid eten op schaal & GSM-applicatie & Kan met beperkte data trends herkennen, eenvoudig, snel & Helemaal niet accuraat 
  \tabularnewline \hline
  Kassaticket scanner applicatie & Kassaticket scanner & Computer of GSM-applicatie & Kan met beperkte data trends herkennen en gezondere alternatieven voorstellen, eenvoudig & Helemaal niet accuraat (is ook niet het doel), omslachtiger
  \tabularnewline \hline
  Chewing-sounds & Chewing-sounds herkennen & Microfoon in oorkanaal & Eenvoudig, snel & Licht invasief, nog niet zo accuraat
  \tabularnewline \hline
  BioRing & BioRing om macro- en micronutrienten te herkennen & BioRing & Eenvoudig, snel & Nog niet accuraat, duurder
  \tabularnewline \hline
  LVL Wearable Hydration Monitor & Tracker die je vochtbalans meet & Tracker die gebruik maakt van nabij-infrarood, bijhorende applicatie & Eenvoudig, snel & Accuraatheid, duurder
  \tabularnewline \hline
  SPÜN & Vork dat bij elke hap de voedingswaarden berekent & Slimme vork (SPÜN), foto's, GSM-applicatie & Eenvoudig, snel, portable & Accuraatheid van foto herkenning is beperkt, duurder
  \tabularnewline \hline
  Slimme vuilnisbakken & Slimme vuilnisbak die trackt wat je weggooit (sensoren) & Slimme vuilnisbak en een applicatie waar de data naar gestuurd wordt & Eenvoudig, snel, kan als stand-alone applicatie feedback geven op je portiegrootte (te veel weggooien, te veel gekocht, ...) & Accuraatheid, duurder, is pas echt krachtig in samenwerking met een applicatie die weet hoeveel er ervoor op het bord lag, niet portable
  \tabularnewline \hline

\caption{Applicaties waarbij verschillende food logging technieken opgelijst staan met de gebruikte hardware, de voordelen en de nadelen} 
\label{table:techniques}
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please do not post code snippets. Show us always a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Without such a *working* example it is hard to find a solution for the problem, especially if we need to use an exact combination of packages to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Off-topic: I would recommend to avoid vertical lines in tabulars. See, e.g., the [`booktabs` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) for more information about nice tabulars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code helps you to fix the problem:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| X | X | X | X | X |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Applicatie}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Techniek}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Hardware en platform}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Voordelen}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Nadelen}} 
\endhead
& & & &\tabularnewline \hline
```